Xcode: CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
Error described in title. I've tried the accepted answer here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709972 and on a few other similar questions here. Nothings worked so far.
Any working solutions for Xcode 15+  ?

Why not just rebuild the asset catalog from scratch and throw away the bad one?

Can you provide more details about your situation?
